# Why can't I pass result of DownloadStringAsync to a variable?

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous

I'm using this code:

in the constructor of the class:

```
 this.wc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
 this.wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://url" + this.a[0] + ".aspx"));
    }

public void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
        {
            string result = (string)e.Result;
            // do something
            this.a.RemoveAt(0);
            if (this.a.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(this.a[0]);
                // keep retrieving
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // display/handle error
        }
    }
```

I understand I can't set the result of `DownloadStringAsync` to a variable because it is `void`, but if I try to do it in `DownloadStringCompletedEvent` handler, it just returns blank. I was trying to separate this into some other class, but I can't return anything from the request because it is async/void or for whatever reason.

I have the above in a class, which is used in the main application class, and I can't set the result of the http request to a variable within the main class. Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you passing `wc_DownloadStringCompleted` in as the callback? I can't see that here..

Comment: i added it in the original post, its in the class constructor

Comment: Are you saying that the value of `e.Result` is an empty string? Have you tried downloading the page with `DownloadString` (the synchronous version) to see if you get anything?

Answer (score 0):

What did you need to see?
it show your source as string and can see this on this way:

```
public void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((string)e.Result);
    }
}
```